# I want to show delete option for a user if he has created particular folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have one folder in that some important data available who are having write in that path one of the user deleted one file.
So i want the delete option who is owner of the particular folder or file.

Please support this.

Regards
Nageswari

Answer (score 0):

UI controls is not how such problems are solved: anyone would be free to just not use a particular tool which would have such "client-side" feature to trivially bypass your efforts.

Instead, this should be solved at the server side — where all the changes to the repository are actually *created.*
For instance [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) is how to protect arbitrary paths of a repository when serving it with the help of a web server.

(FWIW the company behind Subversion has its own Subversion-serving solution which has support for access controls built-in.)